# Replace string into a multiline string

Tags: yq

I have the following yaml file:

```
values: |
  nameOverride: my-service
  fullnameOverride: ""
  namespace: my-ns

  containerApps:
    - name: app-frontend
      image_tag: xxxxxxx
    - name: app-backend
      image_tag: xxxxxxx
```

I'm looking for a way to replace e.g. `xxxxxx` by `yyyyyy` on `containerApps.[app-frontend].image_tag` within a multi-line value (`values: |`).

The output being:

```
values: |
  nameOverride: my-service
  fullnameOverride: ""
  namespace: my-ns

  containerApps:
    - name: app-frontend
      image_tag: yyyyyy
    - name: app-backend
      image_tag: xxxxxxx
```

How this can be accomplished using `yq`?

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Which yq version are you using? - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq). It [decodes](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/encode-decode) the multiline string using `@yamld`, makes the [substitution](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/string-operators#substitute-replace-string) using `sub`, and [encodes](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/encode-decode) the result back using `@yaml`.

```bash
yq '
  .values |= (
    @yamld | (
      .containerApps[] | select(.name == "app-frontend") | .image_tag
    ) |= sub("xxxxxxx", "yyyyyy")
    | @yaml
  )
'
```

```yaml
values: |
  nameOverride: my-service
  fullnameOverride: ""
  namespace: my-ns
  containerApps:
    - name: app-frontend
      image_tag: yyyyyy
    - name: app-backend
      image_tag: xxxxxxx
```

To update the file in-place (instead of just outputting it), use the `-i` flag.

Comment: awesome!! Thank you very much. It works perfectly.

One additional question... in case I need to replace the image_tag no matter the value is set (instead of xxxxxxx can be anything).

Is there a way? @pmf

Comment: @HutgerHauer If the new value is based on the old one, you need the update assignment operator `|=` (as we do with `sub`). If not (when just setting a value unrelated to the old one), the assignment operator `=` suffices, e.g. `… = "new value"`.

Comment: thanks a lot. It's a new value... it works with a small change.

`...    ) |= "yyyyyy"
 `

Thanks a lot once again.